# Counting number of values great than a percentile value across multiple factor levels

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with a set of values and a factor.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:10, 1*30, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
colnames(df)[1] <- "values"
df$factor<- rep(c("Factor.A","Factor.B"), each = 15)
```

What I would like to do is calculate the 75th percentile of values within each group...

```
Percentile_75 <- aggregate(values ~ factor, function(x)
quantile(x,(0.75)), data = df)
```

...and see how many values are greater than each of these thresholds within df for each factor level. I can do this manually for each factor, but in reality I have far more factor levels, so I am guessing there is a neat (possibly dplyr) function that would be able to do this easily? Thank you in advance.

Comment: By construction, you'll have `round(n()*.25)` or thereabouts (depending on ties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `dplyr` you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(factor) %>% 
  summarize(Percentile_75 = quantile(values,0.75),n_sup = sum(values > Percentile_75))

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#       factor Percentile_75 n_sup
#        <chr>         <dbl> <int>
#   1 Factor.A           8.5     4
#   2 Factor.B           8.5     4
```

Comment: OK I reedited again, summarize was smarter than I thought :), deleting my other comments now

Comment: For the counts alone, I guess `df %>% group_by(factor) %>% tally(values > quantile(values, .75))` is more idiomatic... but oh weird, it gives different results.

Answer (score 1):

A data.table approach:

```
   df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:10, 1*30, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
   colnames(df)[1] <- "values"
   df$factor<- rep(c("Factor.A","Factor.B"), each = 15)

   library(data.table)
   df <- setDT(df)

   df[,P_75 := quantile(values, probs = 0.75), by = factor][
  values > P_75, .(unique(P_75),.N), by = factor
   ]

#      factor  V1 N
# 1: Factor.A 7.5 4
# 2: Factor.B 8.0 2
```